# Nice, concrete example of pl-flipping contraction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, examples, minimal-model-program

In a course I'm giving on the MMP, I am discussing the importance of Shokurov's notion of a pl-flipping contraction for showing that flips exist for arbitrary flipping contractions.  Does someone have a nice, concrete (maybe even particularly beautiful) example of a pl-flipping contraction?